# Search for a specific row in the table

Tags: cypress

I have a table that has no unique values in the columns. How to check if there is an appropriate item in the table based on several columns?

For example, in the table below I want to check if there is a `<tr>` containing the title `some` and the value `10`.

```html
<table border>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>title</th>
    <th>value</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>some</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>some</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I would extract the table content to plain JS (e.g. arrays of arrays of strings) then assert on that.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to get this `<tr>` and then append it as the alias `.as ('someRow')`

Comment: Why? Could you [edit] to explain the broader context and constraints?

Comment: The table has a column containing actions (buttons). I need to select a button for a specific item.

Comment: If there's content that gives a row an *identity*, one way to do this is set a `data-` attribute exposing it for testing, e.g. `<tr data-testid="some-10">...</tr>`. Then it's trivial to pick the row you want and you can find whatever controls in it you need.

Comment: Yes this is a workaround. I was hoping that I could use the `.each` function and somehow find the item :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that this should work:

```
cy.get('tr td:contains("some") + td:contains("10")').should('exist')
```

This will look for row `tr` which contains `td` with text "some", as well as `td` that contains text "10", and both the `td` are adjacent siblings.

Of course if you dont want to have hardcoded values, you could do something like this:

```
cy.get(`tr td:contains("${titleVariable}") + td:contains("${valueVariable}")`).should('exist')
```

and before this, assign the proper values to `titleVariable` and `valueVariable`.
Hope it helps!